# How to build a reusable and dynamic input logic with mandatory fields in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, design-patterns

I have a fragment with several spinners and sub-spinner with a certain "logic" behind it. If I make a selection in the first spinner, it could be possible that:

1.) This is already an answer and no more options are available

2.) A second spinner appears and you can choose an item in the second spinner, depending on your choice in the first spinner

3.) Even more it could be possible that the choosen item in the second spinner let an `EditText` appear where you can enter something

This could be an example "logic".

```
Spinner 1 | Spinner 2 | EditText
----------------------------------
Item 1    | -         | -            (No more input necessary, everything done)
Item 2    | Item 1    | -            (A second spinner appears...)
Item 2    | Item 2    | (Activated)  (An EditText appears after selection in Spinner2)
```

I hope it gets somehow clear... so my items and sub-items are saved as several `string-array` in `strings.xml`.

Like:

```
    <string-array name="cat1">
            <item>Item1</item>
            <item>Item2</item>
   </string-array>

   <string-array name="sub_cat1">
            <item>Item1</item>
            <item>Item2</item>
    </string-array>

    ...
```

I need to store them in the `strings.xml` because I want to make my App available in different languages. Actually I am doing something like this:

In my `OnItemSelectedListener` of my first spinner I check which position was selected and then I have a switch/case where I implement the logic. In the `OnItemSelectedListener` of the second spinner I have to do the same and implement a switch/case with the logic (e.g. if an `EditText` should appear or everything is fine and the user can continue)...

So everything is more or less hard-coded. I really don't like this because it is not really maintanable.. If I change the order in the `string-array` I have to correct every switch/case... or if I add something or delete something. But actually I don't know what would be the best way to improve this design.

I could only thing about deleting all the `string-arrays` in the xml and make a single item for everything (for the translation) and build a class where I can define an attribute for `isMandatory` or `hasSubcategories` or maybe `hasChild`.

Is there any pattern or an idea how I could create a maintable and dynamic implementation of my needs? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Android developer myself throughout the years I've always encountered cases in which developers tend to implement everything using Android classes, and Android tools even though it can be easily solved with POJOs.

You should remember that Android is just a framework which lets you interact with the user, it doesn't pretend to do anything else, and we as developers should use it in that context.

Anyways, to tackle your problem I would most diffidently create a [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) data structure of 'Items', and a way to traverse them with a [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) .

BTW: Do not just call them Items, they are only there to solve the specific problem you are tackling. You should name them with (UI) logical context. Since you didn't mention any, for the sake of the example below I will call them Item.

```
interface Item {
    void accept(ItemVisitor itemVisitor);
}

abstract class ItemWithName implements Item {
    private final String name;

    /*CTOR*/

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class SpinnerLeafItem extends ItemWithName {
    /*CTOR*/

    public void accept(ItemVisitor itemVisitor) {
       itemVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class CompositeSpinnerItem extends ItemWithName {
    private final String name;
    private final List<Item> innerItems;

    /*CTOR*/

    public void accept(ItemVisitor itemVisitor) {
       itemVisitor.visit(this);
    }

    /* Getter for inner items */
}

class EditTextItem extends ItemWithName {
    /*CTOR*/

    public void accept(ItemVisitor itemVisitor) {
       itemVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Yes, I am aware that EditTextItem and SpinnerLeafItem are actually holding the  same arguments. But having them both provides extendable code and a type recognition in run-time. If you fail to do so you will have to hold a property which tells you if the item is an edit-text item or a spinner leaf item which violates the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Now you can have a repository interface that will not constrain you to the string.xml implementation, and will provide you with an extendable code which will let you load items from anywhere.

```
interface SpinnerItemsRepository {
    List<Item> getAllItems();
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort and the explanation!I think the composite data structure is good way to start and I will try to implement this structure in my project.Why I am using the `string.xml` is because of the easy multi-language support I get with these files.So I still have to use them,but you are right,I only need them for the names and not to build an array with it. What I don't really get from your example is the visitor pattern.For what do I need the `itemVisitor` and what are the advantages with it?Maybe I just don't get it because I haven't use the Visitor pattern before :-)

Comment: The visitor pattern lets you determine the type of object you are handling in run-time. Lets take a list view that can show either a text message or contact. Now those are two different objects all together with different properties, but they are still drawn in the same list, that's the only thing that is common between them. There are many ways to solve this issue, using visitor is an elegant solution. It lets you handle the concrete item in run-time without having to use instanceOf or any type mechanisms.